# I am very new in AWS Cloud and I am struggling with concept of nested stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Following should be the structure

1.Root stack
2.Webserver stack: All services related to EC2
3.DB stack: All services related to RDS

I refer aws documents but i am struggling with code how to declare security group for rds & ec2 how to take parameters in root stack i am not able to create a stack. Providing the code snippet how to associate the thing with each other would be helpful

Comment: Could provide what you have done so far?

Comment: Can you provide me a code snippet for above structure.

Comment: Here's AWS examples of nested stacks: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-cloudformation.html#w2ab1c19c23c19b5